# Once I use the brush, is there a way to get the non-selected and selected data separately?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

In such a scenario: https://fiddle.jshell.net/rogeraleite/69hxc2tv/

is there a way to get the data selected by the brush and the data that is not selected by the brush separately?

ps: just printing on the console would be enough.

thanks in advance, 
Roger A L

Comment: So is the question here basically whether there is a method like `dimension.top`, but that returns the data outside the current filter? Or are you looking for group aggregations outside the filter?

Comment: + a method like dimension.top, but that returns the data outside the current filter... to be honest, I want to have a better notion concerning how the dc chart manage the data in relation to its interactions. I believe that trough this problem solution I will have a better clue of it.

Comment: dc.js is very simple, it just applies a filter to crossfilter, and then tells all the other charts in the chartgroup to redraw. Crossfilter is more complicated and "magical". I take it you just want to understand what filters have been applied and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extremely inefficient way to do it, ***for learning purposes only***. Basically we will loop through the entire input data set and check if each record exists in the filtered array of records.

I don't think there is any efficient way to do this with the current crossfilter API. If this is something you have a use for besides for just learning, please open an issue on [crossfilter/crossfilter](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter)

```
function print_filtered_records_slowly() {
    function filtered_out(data, dim) {
        var filtered_in = dim.top(Infinity);
        return data.filter(function(d) {
            return filtered_in.indexOf(d)===-1;
        });
    }
    console.log(filtered_out(json, dateDim));
}

timeSparkLine.on('filtered', print_filtered_records_slowly);
dateBarChart.on('filtered', print_filtered_records_slowly);
```

Fork of your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/agLwz6m0/3/